# Warning Message when using if()

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm trying to do the carry out a function on multiple files and I am using this:

```
require(readxl);
require(MESS);
final_df <- NULL;
for(i in CHI.Files){
  PPeakD <- read_excel(paste0('/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                           LungStudyOutput - Whole case/',i), sheet = "Ppeak");
  PPeakD <- PPeakD[c(4,5)]
  colnames(PPeakD)<-c("Time","PPeak")
  PPeakD <- PPeakD[c(which(PPeak$PPeak>0)),]

  PEEP <- read_excel(paste0("~/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                     LungStudyOutput - Whole case/",i), 
                     sheet = "PEEP")
  PEEP <- PEEP[c(4,5)]
  colnames(PEEP)<-c("Time","PEEP")
  PEEP <- PEEP[c(which(PEEP$PEEP>0)),]

  PPeakAdj <- CHI.Files.frame(approx(PPeak$Time, PPeak$PPeak, 
                                     xout = PEEP$Time, method = "linear", rule = 2))
  colnames(PPeakAdj)<-c("Time","PPeakAdj")

  DrivP <- CHI.Files.frame((PPeakAdj$Time),((c(PPeakAdj$PPeakAdj)) - (c(PEEP$PEEP))))
  colnames(DrivP) <- c("Time", "DrivP")
  final_df <- rbind(final_df,DrivP)
}
```

However, when I do I only get the following message:

```
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (!file.exists(path)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (!is_absolute_path(path)) paste0(" in current working directory ('",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Looking for any advice as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

edit:
Made @Jonathan Carroll 's correction error code looks like this:

```
 Error: '/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                           LungStudyOutput - Whole case/013234-1.xls/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                           LungStudyOutput - Whole case/006538-1.xls/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                           LungStudyOutput - Whole case/000478-1.xls/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                           LungStudyOutput - Whole case/025396-1.xls/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                           LungStudyOutput - Whole case/045495-1.xls/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                           LungStudyOutput - Whole case/000443-1.xls/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                           LungStudyOutput - Whole case/020462-1.xls/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                           LungStudyOutput - Whole case/080677-1.xls/Users/andrewmclean/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/

In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (!file.exists(path)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (!is_absolute_path(path)) paste0(" in current working directory ('",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: I have no idea what's in `CHI.Files` but by the looks of it, not just a single value. Comment out the loop and see if you can get it working for a single file before you loop things. Check the contents of variables at each step and ensure they are what you think.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work out of the loop. I think the problem was that my data was 'levelled' and so it was trying to put too much data in...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, this should have a `paste` around its contents, as it is currently trying to provide too many arguments

```
PEEP <- read_excel("~/Dropbox/Research/Andrew/
                 LungStudyOutput - Whole case/",CHI.Files[i], sep='', 
                 sheet = "PEEP")
```

Comment: I didn't notice that - thanks!! I've updated it and I'm still getting a similar message:

          
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (!file.exists(path)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (!is_absolute_path(path)) paste0(" in current working directory ('",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used}